# pyspark multiple when conditions running time is too long

Tags: python, pyspark, case

I need to add new column to my DF based on combination of two different conditions, while one of them is the same and the other is different for each case:

if operation is 'sync' and message contains 'deleted' - then deleted

if operation is 'sync' and message contains 'updated' - then updated

if operation is 'sync' and message contains 'created' - then created

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

operation = "SYNC"
deleted = "was deleted: true"
created = "was created: true"
updated = "was updated: true"
df1 = df.withColumn(
    "synced",
    f.when(
        f.col("operation").contains(operation) & f.col("message").contains(deleted),
        f.lit("deleted"),
    )
    .when(
        f.col("operation").contains(operation) & f.col("message").contains(created),
        f.lit("created"),
    )
    .when(
        f.col("operation").contains(operation) & f.col("message").contains(updated),
        f.lit("updated"),
    ),
)
```

This code works fine, meaning it does the job. But my problem is that it runs too long: for DF with ~168 million rows it runs about 20 mins.

I search 'message' field in this DF for many times for different strings and it usually takes less than a minute to run, but for this specific case running tine is way to high.

What can I do differently in order to reduce running time for this script?

Comment: is it the only transformation you are applying? if you have other transformation before or after, they may be the reason of the long duration.

Comment: YES! THANK YOU!
I didn't think about it that way..
So now the question is how to identify the bottle neck in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Editing my answer to match your comment**

To figure out the bottle neck can be a bit time consuming. You have several transformation in your code, after each of them, add an action, like show or collect for example and measure the time. You will be able to find which transformation is adding the most. Of course, the final action will take more time than the first one because it is a sum of all your transformation but comparing each time after each transformation, you'll be able to figure out if there is a huge gap at one moment.

The other way of analysing is to read the explain plan.
You do all you transformations, you do `df.explain()` and try to understand where is your bottle neck. You can also add it to your question, someone may see where the problem comes from.

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't reduce the running time. But when I switched between this step and previous step than I saw that running time of this step when down (to 30 sec) and running time of the previous step went up to 20. So your other comment is very true. How can I recognize where to improve?